# vCD API request URI '/edgeGateway/{id}/action/manageExternalIpAddresses' returns RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND... Why?

Tags: vcloud-director-rest-api

Following this documentation [Allocate IP Addresses to an Edge Gateway](https://pubs.vmware.com/vca/index.jsp#com.vmware.vcloud.api.tenant.doc_90/GUID-95E3E84C-4862-4178-B786-A4B3528E5EE8.html), the request always return a 404 resource not found error, meaning there is no such URI. Our vCD API supports version 9.0, which should contain that URI which was added since version 5.7.

**Why can't it find that URI?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: you might want to add some more tags, not many people follow the tag you have

Comment: Are you a vCloud Air customer or do you have your own vCloud Director installation? It sounds like the latter ("Our vCD API supports version 9.0") but you're linking to vCloud Air's API documentation. I think this is the documentation you actually want: http://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-80/index.jsp#com.vmware.vcloud.api.reference.doc_90/doc/operations/PUT-GetVdcTemplates.html